# Why are all my Kafka messages being replayed in Storm?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-storm

I'm trying to figure out why all my Kafka messages are getting replayed every time I restart my Storm topology.

My understanding how how it should work were that once the last Bolt have ack'ed the tuple the spout should commit the message on Kafka, and hence I should not see it replay after a restart.

My code is a simple Kafka-spout and a Bolt which just print every message and then ack'ing them.

```
private static KafkaSpout buildKafkaSpout(String topicName) {
    ZkHosts zkHosts = new ZkHosts("localhost:2181");
    SpoutConfig spoutConfig = new SpoutConfig(zkHosts, 
            topicName, 
            "/" + topicName, 
            "mykafkaspout");      /*was:UUID.randomUUID().toString()*/
    spoutConfig.scheme = new SchemeAsMultiScheme(new StringScheme());
    return new KafkaSpout(spoutConfig);
}

public static class PrintBolt extends BaseRichBolt {
    OutputCollector _collector;
    public static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PrintBolt.class);

    @Override
    public void prepare(Map conf, TopologyContext context, OutputCollector collector) {
        _collector = collector;
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(Tuple tuple) {
        LOG.error("PrintBolt.0: {}",tuple.getString(0));
        _collector.ack(tuple);
    }

    @Override
    public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {
        declarer.declare(new Fields("nothing"));
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();

    builder.setSpout("kafka", buildKafkaSpout("mytopic"), 1);
    builder.setBolt("print1", new PrintBolt(),1).shuffleGrouping("kafka");
}
```

I have not provided any config settings than those in the code.

Am I missing a config-setting or what am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**

To clarify, everything works fine until I restart the pipeline.  The below behavior is what I can get in other (non-storm) consumers, and what I expected from the KafkaSpout

*My expectations:*
[image: Expected behavior]

However the actual behavior Im getting using the default setting is the following.   The messages are processed fine up to I stop the pipeline, and then when I restart I get a replay of all the messages, including those (A and B) which I believed I had ack'ed already

*What actually happens:*
[image: EarliestTime, default behavior]

As per the [configuration options](https://github.com/apache/storm/tree/master/external/storm-kafka#how-kafkaspout-stores-offsets-of-a-kafka-topic-and-recovers-in-case-of-failures) mentioned by Matthias, I can change the `startOffsetTime` to `Latest`, however that is literally the latest where the pipeline is dropping the messages (Message "C") that were produced while the pipeline were restarting.

[image: LatestTime, messages dropped]

I have a consume written in NodeJS (using npm kafka-node) which is able to ack messages to Kafka and when I restart the NodeJs consumer it does exactly what I expected (catchup on message "C" which were produced when the consumer were down and continue from there) -- so how do I get the same behavior with the KafkaSpout?

Comment: You mean, as long as the topology is running everything is fine? There are no failed tuples? However, when you kill topology and re-submit it, it processes old tuples again instead of resuming from the last Kafka offset that got processed and acked? (btw: if bolt is a sink as in your case, you don't need to declare an output stream. You can leave `declareOutputFields` empty.)

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://github.com/apache/storm/tree/master/external/storm-kafka#how-kafkaspout-stores-offsets-of-a-kafka-topic-and-recovers-in-case-of-failures

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I mean -- it works fine with no failed tuples, but when restarting I see the replay of the already processes tuples.
Playing around with the startOffsetTime as per your link changes the behavior, and setting it to `LatestTime` the spouit now drops all messages which were sent while the spout was not running -- which is no good either -- so not a solution.

Comment: I see. However, the behavior itself is correct. For your use case, you need to make sure, that the offset is stored in Zookeeper such that it can be picked up at redeploy... From the link: "Important: When re-deploying a topology make sure that the settings for SpoutConfig.zkRoot and SpoutConfig.id were not modified, otherwise the spout will not be able to read its previous consumer state information (i.e. the offsets) from ZooKeeper -- which may lead to unexpected behavior and/or to data loss, depending on your use case." -- It seems something is wrong with Zookeeper in your case.

Comment: Good point, using a random-UUID for the Spout ID wouldn't help -- however I just changed it to a constant value and that had no effect on the behavior.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax -- maybe you could elaborate on why you think the " behavior itself is correct"

Comment: Well, if you specify `LatestTime` the doc says "read from the end of the topic (i.e. any new messsages that are being written to the topic)". It means read messages that will be delivered in the future of deploy time. From your picture, message C was inserted to Kafka while no topology was running, re-deployments happens, and after that, messages D and E got inserted to Kafka and thus are consumed by your topology.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax -- Sure, I was thinking that you meant that replay of all messages as the default behavior (without setting LatestTime)  was a correct behavior.

Comment: Misunderstanding. Sorry for being not precise enough. But now we are on the same page. However, reading all events from the very beginning is default behavior in Kafka. However, KafkaSpout should store the offset and resume at the point it left of.

Comment: ZkHosts zkHosts = new ZkHosts("localhost:2181"); You are not using a production setup, which persists the consumer state... You need to configure kafka

Comment: @SQL.injection -- well almost right, I had actually setup a single node development cluster following [this guide](http://10jumps.com/blog/storm-installation-single-machine), hence the localhost zk  -- but my submit code continued to submit to an instance of LocalCluster, after fixing that everything works .... (feel free to add that as an answer and I will accept that)

Comment: @Soren there is no need for such thing :p. BTW voted up your own answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem were in the submit code -- the template code for submitting the topology will create a instance of `LocalCluster` if the `storm jar` is run without a topology name, and the local cluster does not capture the state and hence the replay.

So

```
$ storm jar myjar.jar storm.myorg.MyTopology topologyname
```

will launch it on my [single node development cluster](http://10jumps.com/blog/storm-installation-single-machine), where

```
$ storm jar myjar.jar storm.myorg.MyTopology
```

will launch it on an instance of `LocalCluster`